# Admob Interstitial ad showing Error building request URL

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have implemented admob interstitial ad recently and getting exception/error as **Error building request URL.** from method onAdFailedToLoad(), and also my ad is not shown
.

My code:

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
                InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
                interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(KEY);
                MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                        Log.e("app","MobileAds onInitializationComplete");
                    }
                });
                interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        Log.e("app","ad loaded");
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        Log.e("app","ad failedToLoad: "+loadAdError.getMessage()); //error/exception here
                    }
                });
}
                  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    Log.e("app","ad loaded");
                }
                else Log.e("app","ad not loaded yet");              
    }
}
```

I have registered my id properly in the Manifest.xml

```
<application>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/KEY"/>
    </application>
```

Followed same guideline [shown in here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en-US)

Comment: use testing id for test.

Comment: If you load => fail => try load again => fail => try load again you may hit the API rate limit that triggers the 3 - Error building request url. I think the limit is 3 request every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you use the correct test ad ID from AdMob in the call InterstitialAd. This is not the same as your App ID, it has an attached slash and a number behind it.

For testing,
use **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712** which is the test ID given by the docs at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that this error occurs in these cases:

- When you type wrong adUnitId.
- When you pass wrong AdSize (ex. too big or too small).
- When Google stops displaying ads in your app, because you break some admob rules.

Comment: I have been having this problem for hours and it indeed seemed that I was having an issue with my adsize. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, after checking I found out that I entered the unit ID incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Never use App id from the console to Test ads in your app. Instead use these sample id's:

| Ad format | Sample Ad Unit Id | How it looks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [App Open](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open) | ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294 | [image] |
| [Banner](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#add_adview) | ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 | [image] |
| [Interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#create_an_interstitial_ad_object) | ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 | No preview |
| [Interstitial Video](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#add_adview) | ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433 | [image] |

And a lot more. You can find all of them [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Answer (score 0):

For instersticial Ad the Sample ad unit ID must be: **`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`**

Here is the demo ad units that point to specific test creatives for each format.

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you add the link to docs and also write this in the form of text